# How to unbrick a HTC Magic?

Tags: htc-magic, unbricking

I have bricked my HTC Magic. Now when I try to boot it normally or in hboot or in fastboot or in recovery, it only shows a white box with an arrow and a bugdroid then a blank screen. It's not detected by adb or fastboot in any mode. Is there a way to unbrick it?

I think I flashed a bad radio. At least, it was after flashing a radio but I thought it was a good one. The old radio version was 2.22 and the new one was a 6.35 and I used ClockworkMode recovery to flash it.

Comment: If you can neither boot to fastboot or recovery, then tough luck; there is not much you can do.

Comment: As you did not provide any information about your workstations OS, it makes things harder. Did you try whether the fastboot tool on your workstation is able to detect your Magic when connected via USB? Is it detected, maybe, by ADB? What did you use for flashing? A few more background data will be necessary to make us able to help :)